# Compress a TensorFlow model

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a ready-to-use tool that can [compress](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.00149v5.pdf) the trained TensorFlow weights ?

This kind of tools exists for Caffe models ([link](https://github.com/yuanyuanli85/CaffeModelCompression))

Answer (score 0):

You can at least [quantize the network](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization) with tensorflow. You'll find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/optimizing) other tools to reduce the graph size to put it on mobile.